# Как сделать скролл столбца таблицы, который содержит другие столбцы?

Tags: html, css, html5

Как сделать скролл столбца таблицы, который содержит другие столбцы?
таблица занимает все пространство доступное по ширине, скролл внутри столбца позволит таблице полностью вместиться в div (внешний скролл по x не должен появляться). Как это реализовать?

до:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th, td {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
            min-width: 50px;
        }

        .scrollable {
            overflow-x: auto;
        }

        .fixed-width {
            width: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="scrollable" style="width: 500px">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Первый столбец</th>
            <th colspan="5">Второй столбец</th>
            <th colspan="5">Третий столбец</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="fixed-width">1</th>
            <th class="fixed-width">2</th>
            <th class="fixed-width">3</th>
            <th class="fixed-width">4</th>
            <th class="fixed-width">5</th>

            <th class="fixed-width">10</th>
            <th class="fixed-width">11</th>
            <th class="fixed-width">12</th>
            <th class="fixed-width">13</th>
            <th class="fixed-width">14</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Данные 1</td>

            <td>Данные 4</td>
            <td>Данные 5</td>
            <td>Данные 6</td>
            <td>Данные 7</td>
            <td>Данные 8</td>

            <td>Данные 4</td>
            <td>Данные 5</td>
            <td>Данные 6</td>
            <td>Данные 7</td>
            <td>Данные 8</td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```